# Translating into German constructions of the type "adjective + adjectivized noun," as in "the blue-eyed girl"

Tags: english-to-german, adjective, compound

> the blue-eyed girl

This English construction can be rendered into German as either of the following:

> Das Mädchen mit den blauen Augen.
>
> Das Mädchen, das blaue Augen hat.

But is there any way of saying that similar to the English construction: *adjective + adjectivized noun* [*blue-eyed*]?

Answer (score 6):

The shortest is:

> Das [blauäugige](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/blauaeugig) Mädchen.

Comment: Can you use this pattern for any other example, as you can in English?

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 Which other constructions do you mean? E.g. "braunhaarig" for "brown-haired" is possible. But I don't know any more...

Comment: Is that girl naive or why is she *blauäugig*?

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328, indeed you can use that in other examples. You should not use it in this case, though, because *blauäugig* happens to have another meaning.

Comment: @CarstenS You can not use it in written language, but in spoken you could emphasize that you not mean the naive meaning by leaving a small gap in between "blau" and "äugige", thus emphasizing that you mean the standard connection of the two words and not the alternative meaning.

Comment: @IQV "langbeinig", "dunkelhäutig", "breitschultrig", "graubärtig", ...

Comment: @Uwe Danke! Ich hoffe nur, der OP meint nicht eine englische Konstruktion, die im Deutschen eben doch nicht geht.

Comment: It's a common pattern: *das kurzärmelige Hemd*, *die dickbauchige Vase*. Such words often become proper adjectives: *der langweilige Vortrag*. But noun+adjective is more common: *die messerscharfe Schnittkante*, *das nagelneue Kleid*

Comment: @Em1: Dass deutsche Wörter mehr als eine Bedeutung haben, ist ja eher Regel als Ausnahme. Was gemeint ist, muss aus dem Kontext hervorgehen.

Answer (score 4):

In German there is exactly this construction (adjective + adjectivized noun), but we don't need a hyphen for it. I even guess, that this construction is even more often used in German than in English:

> das blauäugige Mädchen
>   the blue-eyed girl
>
> der dunkelhaarige Mann
>   The dark-haired man
>
> die langbeinige Frau
>   the long-legged woman
>
> der breitschultrige Kerl
>   the wide-shouldered guy

but also

> das kurzärmelige Hemd
>   the short-armed shirt
>
> das dünnwandige Glas
>   the thin-walled glass

and of course

> der dickhäutige Elefant
>   the thick-skinned elephant

Comment: Note that *blauäugig*  is used figuratively (for *naiv*) much more often than directly,  so this particular example is awkward. But the response about the general pattern is spot-on.